# Returning database results as a stream

Tags: c#, stream

I have a function that returns database query results.  These results have got very large, and I now would like to pass them as a stream, so that the client can start to process them quicker, and memory usage is less.  But I don't really know how to do this, the following function works, but what I want to know how to change it so that it starts to stream upon reading from the first table.

```
    public Stream GetResults()
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();

        formatter.Serialize(stream, GetItemsFromTable1());
        formatter.Serialize(stream, GetItemsFromTable2());
        formatter.Serialize(stream, GetItemsFromTable3());
        formatter.Serialize(stream, GetItemsFromTable4());

        stream.Position = 0;            
        return stream;
    }
```

Comment: `so that it starts to stream` so *what* starts to stream? Are you asking for how the consumer can start processing Table1 while that code works on Table2, 3 and 4?

Comment: How are you actually processing and forwarding the results now? Maybe a [yield return](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) serves your purpose more than a stream?

Comment: Do you just want to pass all resultsets from the database to the client  behind the stream (w/o much transformation) or are items full .net objects that needs to be serialized? What kind of database? any? what kind of client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom `Stream` implementation which functions as a pipe.  If you then moved your `GetItemsFromTable()` method calls into a background task, the client could start reading results from the stream immediately.

In my solution below I'm using a circular buffer as a backing store for the pipe stream.  Memory usage will be reduced only if the client consumes data fast enough.  But even in the worst case scenario it shouldn't use more memory then your current solution.  If memory usage is a bigger priority for you than execution speed then your stream could potentially block write calls until space is available. My solution below does *not* block writes; it expands the capacity of the circular buffer so that the background thread can continue filling data without delays.

The GetResults method might look like this:

```
public Stream GetResults()
{
    // Begin filling the pipe with data on a background thread
    var pipeStream = new CircularBufferPipeStream();
    Task.Run(() => WriteResults(pipeStream));

    // Return pipe stream for immediate usage by client
    // Note: client is responsible for disposing of the stream after reading all data!
    return pipeStream;
}

// Runs on background thread, filling circular buffer with data
void WriteResults(CircularBufferPipeStream stream)
{
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, GetItemsFromTable1());
    formatter.Serialize(stream, GetItemsFromTable2());
    formatter.Serialize(stream, GetItemsFromTable3());
    formatter.Serialize(stream, GetItemsFromTable4());

    // Indicate that there's no more data to write
    stream.CloseWritePort();
}
```

And the circular buffer stream:

```
/// <summary>
/// Stream that acts as a pipe by supporting reading and writing simultaneously from different threads.
/// Read calls will block until data is available or the CloseWritePort() method has been called.
/// Read calls consume bytes in the circular buffer immediately so that more space is available for writes into the circular buffer.
/// Writes do not block; the capacity of the circular buffer will be expanded as needed to write the entire block of data at once.
/// </summary>
class CircularBufferPipeStream : Stream
{
    const int DefaultCapacity = 1024;
    byte[] _buffer;
    bool _writePortClosed = false;
    object _readWriteSyncRoot = new object();
    int _length;
    ManualResetEvent _dataAddedEvent;
    int _start = 0;

    public CircularBufferPipeStream(int initialCapacity = DefaultCapacity)
    {
        _buffer = new byte[initialCapacity];
        _length = 0;
        _dataAddedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }

    public void CloseWritePort()
    {
        lock (_readWriteSyncRoot)
        {
            _writePortClosed = true;
            _dataAddedEvent.Set();
        }
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return true; } }
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return true; } }
    public override bool CanSeek { get { return false; } }
    public override void Flush() { }
    public override long Length { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
    public override long Position
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public override void SetLength(long value) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            bool waitForData = false;
            lock (_readWriteSyncRoot)
            {
                if (_length != 0)
                    bytesRead = ReadDirect(buffer, offset, count);
                else if (_writePortClosed)
                    break;
                else
                {
                    _dataAddedEvent.Reset();
                    waitForData = true;
                }
            }
            if (waitForData)
                _dataAddedEvent.WaitOne();
        }
        return bytesRead;
    }

    private int ReadDirect(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int readTailCount = Math.Min(Math.Min(_buffer.Length - _start, count), _length);
        Array.Copy(_buffer, _start, buffer, offset, readTailCount);
        _start += readTailCount;
        _length -= readTailCount;
        if (_start == _buffer.Length)
            _start = 0;

        int readHeadCount = Math.Min(Math.Min(_buffer.Length - _start, count - readTailCount), _length);
        if (readHeadCount > 0)
        {
            Array.Copy(_buffer, _start, buffer, offset + readTailCount, readHeadCount);
            _start += readHeadCount;
            _length -= readHeadCount;
        }

        return readTailCount + readHeadCount;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        lock (_readWriteSyncRoot)
        {
            // expand capacity as needed
            if (count + _length > _buffer.Length)
            {
                var expandedBuffer = new byte[Math.Max(_buffer.Length * 2, count + _length)];
                _length = ReadDirect(expandedBuffer, 0, _length);
                _start = 0;
                _buffer = expandedBuffer;
            }

            int startWrite = (_start + _length) % _buffer.Length;
            int writeTailCount = Math.Min(_buffer.Length - startWrite, count);
            Array.Copy(buffer, offset, _buffer, startWrite, writeTailCount);
            startWrite += writeTailCount;
            _length += writeTailCount;
            if (startWrite == _buffer.Length)
                startWrite = 0;

            int writeHeadCount = count - writeTailCount;
            if (writeHeadCount > 0)
            {
                Array.Copy(buffer, offset + writeTailCount, _buffer, startWrite, writeHeadCount);
                _length += writeHeadCount;
            }
        }
        _dataAddedEvent.Set();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_dataAddedEvent != null)
            {
                _dataAddedEvent.Dispose();
                _dataAddedEvent = null;
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Roger. I had got as far as your GetResults function, almost exactly as you had it, but could not get it to work with a standard MemoryStream.  Your custom circular stream should do it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public Stream GetResults()
{
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();

    formatter.Serialize(stream, GetItemsFromTable1());
    formatter.Serialize(stream, GetItemsFromTable2());
    formatter.Serialize(stream, GetItemsFromTable3());
    formatter.Serialize(stream, GetItemsFromTable4());

    stream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return stream;
}
```

why the changes?

- remove using, because your stream gets disposed once it leaves the using-block. disposing the stream means you cannot use it anymore
- seek to the beginning of the stream. if you start reading from the stream without seeking to its beginning, you would start to deserialize/ read from its end; but unfortunately there is no content behind the end of the stream

however, I don't see how using a `MemoryStream` reduces memory usage. I would suggest chaining it into a `DeflateStream` or a `FileStream` to reduce RAM-usage

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks - your point on both using, and the stream position are valid; but they don't answer my question on starting to read the stream whilst it is still writing